# Push notification on iOS - Notification.requestPermission not working

Tags: ios, safari-push-notifications

Currently I am working on a project implement push notifications dashboard to send notifications to users, be that in desktop or mobile.

Currently it is working for all desktop-based browsers as well as android.
On iOS though, the pop up to allow notifications does not appear, at all.

I read around that there are some blockers when it comes to push notifications on iOS for PWA. Is there any workaround for this?

PS: Let me know if it is the case to share a piece of the code.

I created the manifest.json to turn the web app into PWA. I added it to Home Screen already, the service worker gets registered but when the Notification.requestPermission() call apparently is not called. The pop up alert does not appear, consequently I can`t subscribe the service worker.

Comment: I have the same issue, but in Chrome (Android)

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track by adding the PWA to your home screen and using a background service worker to fire off notifications.

Seeing your code would help me better tailor this answer, but provided your iOS version supports push notifications, something like this (for `reactjs`) should work for prompting users to enable notifications and registering/updating the worker as needed:

```js
const AppComponent = ({}) => {

  const [displayNotif, setDisplayNotif] = useState(false);
  const [isTokenFound, setTokenFound] = useState(false);

  function reqNotifPerm() {
    try {
      Notification.requestPermission().then((result) => {
        if (result === "granted") {
          try {
            setTokenFound(true);
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
          }
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      if (!(isTokenFound)) {
        setDisplayNotif(true);
      } else if (isTokenFound) {
        setDisplayNotif(false);
        getFBToken(setTokenFound);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  },[isTokenFound]);

  return (
    //...
    {displayNotif && <div onClick={() => { reqNotifPerm() }}>
      {"Enable Notifications"}
    </div>}
    //...
  );
};
```